# Hide Sitecore Form fields if user is authenticated

Tags: sitecore-forms

**Environment:** Sitecore 9.2 & SXA 1.9

**Scenario:** I have created a Sitecore form, which consists of three fields and a submit button. Now I would like to hide one of the fields if the user is authenticated (extranet - logged in). Suppose, Form ABC has three `Single-Line Text` fields: Name, Contact, and Country. If the user is logged in then the Country field should not be visible to the user.

How to achieve this functionality? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option that could work is using Sitecore security. As each form element is an item in Sitecore, you can set security on it. If you deny read access to your logged-in users for the country item it will not be visible on the form. Other users that do have read access will still see the field.